# JavaScript - MVC.NET: Get value of Multimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the value of a multidimensional `int[][]` array on JavaScript.

The array is initialized at the Controller class and passed to the JS through the View class in a Hidden input element called `hdn_l_asuetos`.

The problem is that I need to iterate over that `int[][]` array into de JavaScript file, but I cant. 
Here my JS code:

```
var natDays = $('#hdn_l_asuetos').val();

function nationalDays(date, inMonth) {
    if (inMonth) {
        for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
            alert("MES " + natDays[i][0]);
            alert("DIA " + natDays[i][1]);
            if (date.getMonth() + 1 == natDays[i][0] &&
                    date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
                return {selectable: false};
            }
        }
    }
    return {};
}
```

I am getting this result:

```
MES S
DIA undefined
MES y
DIA undefined
MES s
DIA undefined
MES t
DIA undefined
MES e
DIA undefined
MES m
DIA undefined
MES .
DIA undefined
MES I
DIA undefined
MES n
DIA undefined
MES t
DIA undefined
MES 3
DIA undefined
MES 2
DIA undefined
MES [
DIA undefined
MES ]
DIA undefined
MES [
DIA undefined
MES ]
DIA undefined
```

With that I can see that `var natDays = $('#hdn_l_asuetos').val();` is returning the Type of `hdn_l_asuetos`, System.Int32[][] at position 0.

I will appreciate any help to iterate over the `int[][]` array.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly are you assigning your double array into the '#hdn_l_asuetos' element in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing multi-dimensional array elements the right way

```
arr[i][j]
```

However when you are doing

```
var natDays = $('#hdn_l_asuetos').val();
```

You getting a string as `natDays`

I think you did this on the server side:

```
System.Int32[][] myArr = ....

and in razor view

... @myArr
```

which effectively executed

```
myArr.ToString()
```

and you received  `"System.Int32[][]"` value in your input control

What you should've done is JSON serialize you array on the server side and then deserialize it on the client

```
//in view
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(myArr))


//js 
var natDaysJson = $('#hdn_l_asuetos').val();
var natDays = JSON.parse(natDaysJson)
```

then all the remaining code will stay unchanged

Alternatively if this piece of javascript lives in the razor view you can directly assign array to your variable

```
var natDays = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(myArr))
```

this way when view will be rendered you will have you array as object literal:

```
var natDays = [ [ 1,2,3] , [4,5,6]... ]
```

Comment: Thanks @vittore. This solved the issue: In the view: `@Html.Hidden("hdn_l_asuetos", Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.l_asuetosToAvoid)))`.                             In the JS:                                                        `var natDaysJson = $('#hdn_l_asuetos').val();
var natDays = JSON && JSON.parse(natDaysJson) || $.parseJSON(natDaysJson);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON to stringify your double array value into a string before you assign it to the input's value, then when you retrieve it, use JSON to parse it back.  If you are just literally assigning the double array value to the value property of the element, it won't work as it can only store strings.  What you are getting is probably the array interpreted as a string in the wrong way.